# Which in-memory cache should be used?

Tags: java, guava, ehcache, hazelcast, dropwizard

We are having a use case where we wanted to have a in memory cache which can have capability to store key and value with different TTLs. We know some in memory caches like Guava, Hazelcast and Ehcache. We tried with Guava but it has the problem that it decides TTL using expireAfterAccess and expireAfterWrite methods. These will have a constant value for all rows in cache. So, that is the problem. So, here all data will expire after X hours after it was written. Though TTL will be different. But I want something in which while set key, value pair, I can set the TTL also at that time.

Also, we are using dropwizard framework, so it would be great that this in memory cache is quite easy to integrate with DropWizard Framework.

Please suggest some in memory cache which we should use for our use case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was in a same situation some time ago and didn't find Guava's cache very usable for my use case; and it looked a bit too complicated. I was looking for something like [HttpRuntime.Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in *.NET*. As it wasn't such an important feature, I've decided to implement it myself quickly and go back to it later. It might be buggy or not the most optimized though.

I've used SHA256 (256 for FIPS compliancy) to keep their hash so I can find them fast; but your use-case could have a better approach to that. Also, my objects have expiration time in them, so you might need to modify the code to store the expiration time somewhere.

```
  private final ExecutorService executorService;
  private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyObject> objectCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  private Instant lastObjectCacheCleanupTime = Instant.now();
  private static final TemporalAmount cacheCleanupFrequency = Duration.ofHours(1);

  private void cacheObject(String encodedObject, MyObject object) {
    executorService.submit(() -> {
      objectCache.put(DigestUtils.sha256Hex(encodedObject), object);

      synchronized (objectCache) {
        if (Instant.now().isAfter(lastObjectCacheCleanupTime.plus(cacheCleanupFrequency))) {
          lastObjectCacheCleanupTime = Instant.now();
          objectCacheCleanup();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private Optional<MyObject> getObjectFromCache(String encodedObject){
    String digest = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(encodedObject);

    if (!objectCache.containsKey(digest)) {
      return Optional.empty();
    }

    MyObject myObject = objectCache.get(digest);

    if (myObject.isExpired())
       objectCache.remove(digest);
       return Optional.empty();
    }

    return Optional.of(myObject);
  }


  private void objectCacheCleanup() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, MyObject> digestObjectEntry : objectCache.entrySet()) {
      if (digestObjectEntry.getValue().isExpired()) {
        objectCache.remove(digestObjectEntry.getKey());
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Memcached** . There are different memcached clients for Java 
https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients#Java

I have used spymemcached client . 
Example from : https://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/wiki/Examples

// Get a memcached client connected to several servers

```
MemcachedClient c=new MemcachedClient(
        AddrUtil.getAddresses("server1:11211 server2:11211"));
```

// Try to get a value, for up to 5 seconds, and cancel if it doesn't return

```
Object myObj=null;
Future<Object> f=c.asyncGet("someKey");
try {
    myObj=f.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch(TimeoutException e) {
    // Since we don't need this, go ahead and cancel the operation.  This
    // is not strictly necessary, but it'll save some work on the server.
    f.cancel(false);
    // Do other timeout related stuff
}
```

In same way you can set the values with different ttl

```
Future<Object> f=c.set(key, ttl, data);
```

In dropwizard  you can implement Managed Interface for initalizing and stoping memchached client 
http://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html#managed-objects

```
public class MemcachedManger implements Managed {
    private  MemcachedClient client;

    public MemcachedManger() {
        // write a constructor for initializing custom dependencies of this class 
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        // create new object of memcachedClient
        this.client=new MemcachedClient(AddrUtil.getAddresses("server1:11211 server2:11211"));
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        client.shutdown();
    }


    // define get and put and any other custom methods using functionality provided by spymemchached client 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com/). They have a method to put an entry with a TTL value. See http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#put(K, V, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

From the Javadoc:

*Puts an entry into this map with a given ttl (time to live) value. Entry will expire and get evicted after the ttl. If ttl is 0, then the entry lives forever.*

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work for Terracotta (Software AG)*

[Ehcache](http://ehcache.org) provides this feature.

Once an [`Element`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.10/net/sf/ehcache/Element.html) has been created, TTL and TTI can be set on it before putting it in the cache.